# How to make an animated ListView?

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-phone-8.1

I realised that storyboard only working with silverlight Wp 8.1 apps. So what about non-silverlight? I've want to make an animation of smooth appearing elements of listview after page transition. How can i make it? I check VisualStateGroup, but to make animation like that i should make a code behind. Is it possible to make only by XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `XAML` you can use the built in transitions which you can choose from already predefined ones. One drawback is that you can't create your own transitions this way.

To change the item transitions change the `ItemContainerTransitions` property on your `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <!--<ContentThemeTransition HorizontalOffset="0"/>-->
            <!--<EntranceThemeTransition />-->
            <!--  <AddDeleteThemeTransition />  -->
            <!--  <RepositionThemeTransition/>  -->
            <!--  <ReorderThemeTransition />  -->
            <!--  <PopupThemeTransition/>  -->
            <!--  <EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Top"/>  -->
        </TransitionCollection>
    </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
</ListView>
```

You can combine them if you want. Just uncomment any of the above code and use which suits you best.

You can create custom item animations when you extend `ListView` and override the `GetContainerForItemOverride` or `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` methods. You can use XAML if you want for example a `Storyboard` defined in as a `StaticResource`. Here is an example:

```
    public class MyListView : ListView
    {
        protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
        {
            var container = base.GetContainerForItemOverride();
            var da = new DoubleAnimation();
            // init da...
            var sb = new Storyboard();
            // initi sb with container
            sb.Begin();
            return container;
        }

        protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
        {
            base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

            var da = new DoubleAnimation();
            // init da...
            var sb = new Storyboard();
            // initi sb with element
            sb.Begin();
        }
    }
```

Comment: U're the best. Thank you ! (i know that comments not for saying "thanks", but anyway)

Comment: @Kristian, will  ReorderThemeTransition have an effect when adding a new item at the end of the list? In other words, will the listview items animate when new item(s) are added to the listview? Thank you